WaitForSingleObject Returns Right Away When Called On Sleeping Thread
I have a thread that sleeps for long periods of time and when it comes time to shut it down I set an atomic variable that both the main program and the thread have access to and call WaitForSingleObject from the main program to wait until the thread exits.  However, WaitForSingleObject returns right away with a WAIT_OBJECT_0 response telling me the thread has exited which can't be true cause it's sleeping (it sleeps for a minute at a time via the Sleep function and there's no way my call to WaitForSingleObject is always right before it wakes up and checks the shared variable).
My code to stop the thread is pretty straightforward:
gStopThread = true;
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, WAIT_INFINITE);
CloseHandle(hThread);

and in the thread I have:
while (!gStopThread)
{
   Sleep(60000);
   ...
}

Is this normal behavior from WaitForSingleObject?  Does calling WaitForSingleObject possibly wake the thread up after which point it checks the shared variable and exits?  But if that were the case the code after the Sleep function would get executed but it's not.  Or does calling WaitForSingleObject on a sleeping thread simply shut the thread down (ie: it dies in its sleep)?  Or is there another way to wait for a thread that is sleeping to wake up and gracefully exit?

Yes there is, stop using the windows API for threading. You will find std::thread/std::jthread, std::mutex, std::scoped_lock/std;:unique_lock and std::condition_variable are much easier to use (follow RAII principles). std::condition_variable is an excellent way to be able to wait of 60 seconds OR a shutdown flag.

This is not expected behavior. Is it possible that your hThread was already closed, and the value got reused for something else? You can use the !handle debugger command to see what hThread refers to. (Also, I assume that WAIT_INFINITE is a typo for INFINITE.)

As mentioned above, this is not the expected behavior. Please post a [mre].

On a side note, you should use an event object instead of an atomic variable. That way, your thread can still sleep the full time period during normal execution, but your termination will be able to wake it up immediately so you don't have to wait for a full sleep period.

@PepijnKramer while the standard does provide basic threading via std::thread/jthread, there are a lot of cases where you can't avoid using the Windows API, for example with WaitForMultipleObjects or with thread pools.

@MichaelChourdakis I would disagree with "a lot of cases". I've been developing on windows for a long time and windows API calls (if used at all) are only at the edges of the code base (behind abstract base classes). Most of the code I write is OS agnostic (helps a lot with unit testability too). So yes I could be biased to C++ standard threading :)

@PepijnKramer "Most of the code I write is OS agnostic (helps a lot with unit testability too)." - How does the former help with the latter?

@IInspectable because I have those calls behind abstract baseclasses (interfaces) so I can mock/stub them too (to mimick error conditions etc).

usually you not need use global gStopThread but can set evet, inject APC to thread, alert him (by id).

I suggest you could refer to the Doc: Terminating a Thread You could try to create an event object.Each thread monitors the event state by calling the WaitForSingleObject function. When the event is set to the signaled state, each thread terminates its own execution.
